# What is the alternate way to write this generator in Python 3?

Tags: python, generator, iterable

I dont quite understand this generator, although it is for simplicity, i would appreciate if anyone knows an alternate why of coding this with the same result using like a loop or something.

```
yield from [i for i, k in self.iterate(self.key)]
```

Don't worry about the context, I'm hoping you have enough information to write an alternate way to represent this generator return. If not i can post more.

Thanks guys.

Comment: "An alternate way"? "The alternate way"? What requirements would you like the solution to satisfy? This question doesn't seem particularly clear to me.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out differnt ways of coding generators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for i, k in self.iterate(self.key):
    yield i
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: what about something like:

Comment: yield from [i for i in self.iterate(self.key)]

Comment: @Team.Coco What you mean by *what about?* You can use this answer in order to understand the functionality of `yield from` then just use it in another cases.

Comment: how would i represent that with a for loop? I tried:

Comment: for i in self.iterate(self.key):    yield i, but it didnt give me the same result

Comment: Nevermind, typo i got it. Thank you